# Is ngx-pagination efficient with firestore collection?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ngx-pagination

I'm working in a Angular+Firestore application web and I recently have required to paginate some documents from a collection in Firestore. I use ngx-pagination and it works well. I use it in client, not in server.

My question is that my actual collection is short, but if a had one large (very large), will ngx-pagination continue being efficient to paginate Firestore collection?

A more precise question: ngx-pagination load all the data from a firestore collection or it paginate it to show when necessary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are doing server-side pagination, ngx-pagination will always load the whole data from the collection. If you expect the data to increase a lot, I would recommend you to implement either server-side pagination as mentioned [here](http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/), or implement the data pagination mentioned in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)